# bind DataGridComboBoxColumn from code

Tags: .net, wpf, datagrid

I have this columns in datagrid wpf

```
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridComboBoxColumn SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=ProductId}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" />         
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=StorageAmount}" Width="*" Header="Со склада" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Trade1Amount}" Width="*" Header="С точки 1" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=Trade2Amount}" Width="*" Header="С точки 2" />
            <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=TotalAmount}" Width="*" Header="Всего" FontWeight="Bold" />
        </DataGrid.Columns>
```

How can I bind *DataGridComboBoxColumn* programmatically from code, not from xaml? I can't define *Name* to *DataGridComboBoxColumn* so I can't access from code in order to fill *DataContext* of this Combobox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the x:-namespace with the Name-attribute. This will do what you're looking for:

```
<DataGridComboBoxColumn x:Name="m_yourComboBoxColumn" SelectedItemBinding="{Binding Path=ProductId}" DisplayMemberPath="Name" SelectedValuePath="Id" />
```